# Passing asynchronous task result from one library (NPoco) to another (Polly) - which approach to use?

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, polly, npoco

**Background**

In my C# project (.NET 5.0), I am using NPoco (an ORM) to run SQL commands. I am then looking to execute the calls via a retry policy using Polly (e.g. if certain transient SQL errors occur, then retry up to N times).

For synchronous calls, this is straightforward. However, for asynchronous calls, I can see at least 3 ways to do it. Essentially, the difference between my 3 ways is in whether or not they use Polly's and NPoco's own synchronous method or asynchronous methods. Note that I cannot see the internals of these methods.

**The question**

All the below methods build OK, and appear to work. My question is - is there any difference (functionally, reliability or performance-wise) between these approaches?

**Code samples**

Note that a Polly policy has a synchronous method: `T Execute(Func<T> action)`
and an asynchronous method: `Task<T> ExecuteAsync(Func<Task<T>> action)`

Here is my synchronous method (synchronous Polly and NPoco methods):

```
public T GetScalar<T>(string sql, params object[] args)
{
    return _policy.Execute(() => _npoco.ExecuteScalar<T>(sql, args));
}
```

Here is my asynchronous method #1 (asynchronous Polly and NPoco methods):

```
public async Task<T> GetScalarAsync1<T>(string sql, params object[] args)
{
    return await _policy.ExecuteAsync(() => _npoco.ExecuteScalarAsync<T>(sql, args));
}
```

Here is my asynchronous method #2 (asynchronous Polly and synchronous NPoco methods):

```
public async Task<T> GetScalarAsync2<T>(string sql, params object[] args)
{
    return await _policy.ExecuteAsync(() => Task.Run(() => _npoco.ExecuteScalar<T>(sql, args)));
}
```

Here is my asynchronous method #3 (synchronous Polly and NPoco methods, run as task):

```
public async Task<T> GetScalarAsync3<T>(string sql, params object[] args)
{
    return await Task.Run(() => _policy.Execute(() => _npoco.ExecuteScalar<T>(sql, args)));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this version since `ExecuteScalarAsync` most probably can take advantage of non-blocking async I/O:

```
await _policy.ExecuteAsync(() => _npoco.ExecuteScalarAsync<T>(sql, args));
```

or you could use `async`-`await` inside the `ExecuteAsync` as well

```
await _policy.ExecuteAsync(async () => await _npoco.ExecuteScalarAsync<T>(sql, args));
```

By [definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-7.0) `Task.Run`:

> Queues the specified work to run on the ThreadPool and returns a task or `Task<TResult>` handle for that work

In other words it is not designed for async I/O rather to kick off a CPU intensive computation in the background.

Comment: Thanks. Also the following articles seem to agree that using Tasks as per my methods #2 and #3 are "fake-asynchronous methods": https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/